# Setup .NET Core App in TFS (Visual Studio Team Services)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

When I build my .NET CoreApp in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), the build breaks with this message:

> "GETSDKTOOLINGINFO(0,0): Error : The project is configured to use .NET
>   Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 which is not installed or
>   cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet. These
>   components are required to build and run this project. Download the
>   version of .NET Core SDK specified in global.json or update the SDK
>   version in global.json to the version that is installed."

Any idea how to fix this? Since it's VS Team Services and everything is supposed to be preinstalled.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you're using the Hosted Pool?

In that case you'll need to wait for Microsoft to update the image of the hosted agent. [Microsoft keeps a list of what's installed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software). As of this moment the following .NET Core SDK is installed:

> .NET Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling

You may be able to perform a silent install by downloading the SDK in a build step and installing it as part of every build.